# How to say thank you in StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

I have asked a lot of questions and got many answers in ***StackExchange***. When I want to express my appreciation, I can only use "Thanks" or "I appreciate that." Can anyone teach me more about how to say "Thanks" and how to praise those people who have done good job?

Comment: By participating actively. More on meta.

Comment: I like the more formal expression **Thank you**. But **Thanks** is undoubtedly more frequently used. **Thank you. I appreciate your {time/effort/interest}** is also fine. Don't overdo the praise. Being too effusive in English sounds too [toadyish](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/toadyish): it's [obsequious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsequious).

Comment: I agree with what @BillFranke said. Anything much stronger than "Thank you very much" can be seen as overdone. In face-to-face conversation, one could say, "Thanks a lot – I really mean that" with the latter part emphasizing that you're genuinely thanking a person, and not just saying hollow words.

Comment: No thanks necessary. But if you really do want to express your gratitude, nothing says "thank you" like money.

Answer (score 11):

On any Stack Exchange site, the only way you should thank somebody for their answer is to click the wee tick mark.  Optionally upvote the answer too.  The sites are intended to be collections of questions and answers; not repositories for expressions of gratitude.

On the wider issue of thanking people in other contexts, just saying "thanks" or "thank you" is usually sufficient, unless the effort that the person expended was particularly great.

Answer (score 7):

The Stack Exchange way of saying *thank you* to users is:

- Accepting the answers for your questions that helped you the most
- Up-voting the answers for questions asked from other users that helped you the most, or that you think more correct
- Offering bounties for answers that you think exemplary

With this I don't mean you should up-vote random answers given from a user simply because that user helped you once. Up-vote an answer only if it has merit, or a question if it has merit, or it is helpful/useful.

Saying *thank you* in a comment would mean to use comments for [a purpose different from the one for which comments are thought](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

> #### When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Leaving thanks in the question is disliked, as it is preferable the question contains just the question, in the same way answers should contain just the answer.