# Is there a place on this site where users can express their admiration and gratitude for this site?

Tags: discussion

I am truly impressed with this site. It encourages so many good things as positive curiosity, research, mutual help, voluntary service, elegance and nobility, but also honesty. I am grateful for what I learn and for the diversity of approach to language issues. At first, I was somewhat taken aback by some of the rules of this site, but I gradually came to understand that these rules are its strength to keep up the quality of the information offered and avoid chaotic random communication. Whoever made this site has benefitted many.

Just wondered if here is a good place to say it.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Yes, this is a good place to say it. And you’re welcome. :)

Comment: Related: [I just wanted to say: Thank you!](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6863/) and [As a newcomer I would like to say Thank You](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10863/as-a-newcomer-i-would-like-to-say-thank-you) and [How to say thank you in StackExchange?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/)

Comment: and finally [My first experience with trying to get a question reopened after it was put on hold](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4457/)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Super-nice to see I am not the only one thinking that way! :-)

Comment: Well it makes a pleasant change, there are so few users who take the time to write a nice "Thank you" :)  

Comment: @Mari-Lou It's true, but I'd take it also this way: Their mere presence on this site and every personal contribution is a sign of gratitude, even though it may be mingled with other things. We all find the site good enough to stay. That says something about the site.

Comment: I echo these sentiments. The site is a fine counterbalance to hubris, is unforgiving of mere assertion, questions prejudice, offers firm but courteous exchange of opinion, encourages wider viewpoints, is informative and entertaining, if occasionally a little addictive (is that phrase a specially namable construction like “slightly pregnant”, I wonder?)

Comment: You are still in the early, idyllic phase of your experience on this site…..which is usually the most enjoyable one. 1) https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/why-are-elus-users-so-easily-irritated 2) https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/why-are-elus-users-so-easily-irritated 3) https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13458/reporting-rude-comments. and so on…

Comment: @user66974: I am not sure I am still in that "idyllic" phase. I am presently dealing with [something](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15021/what-happens-when-you-flag-a-rude-comment-and-then-the-author-deletes-it) similar to what you have pointed out, but that does not prevent me from seeing the value of the site. I agree, the atmosphere can get pretty acid in here, but look at the result. You have been here for 5 years and 4 months, and you are still here. I hope to reach your longevity one day :-)

Comment: @user66974 well at least the first and the second complaints are the same!